# How to access the entire TV Provider database by TV Input Manager?

Tags: android, android-tv

According to the [Android docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tv#tv_input_manager)

> TV Inputs provided and signed by the device manufacturer (signature
> apps) or other apps installed in the system partition will have access
> to the entire TV Provider database. This access can be used to
> construct apps to browse and search across all available TV channels
> and programs.

Assuming I signed as device manufacturer or installed app in system partition, how can I access the TvProvider and thus its channel information?

EDIT:

```
val tifSupport: Boolean = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LIVE_TV)
Log.d("XXX", "TIF Support ? $tifSupport")
```

This line says true. Then I run these lines:

```
val tvInputManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(TV_INPUT_SERVICE) as TvInputManager?
Log.d("XXX", "TvInputManager $tvInputManager")

val il = tvInputManager?.tvInputList
Log.d("XXX", "TvInputList size --> ${il?.size}")

tvInputManager?.tvInputList?.forEach { info ->
    Log.d("XXX", "TvInputListInfo ${info.id} ${info.serviceInfo} # ${info.extras.size()}")
}
```

First log prints

> TvInputManager android.media.tv.TvInputManager@95728c2

so the tvInputManager looks valid. Second shows 0 as the TvInputList size and thus third log (in forEach()) is **not** printed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start with background for Android. By provider in the doc, they mean `ContentProvider`, which will share information between process within Android. Now to start with:

- If TV Provider supported by our system.
- If All the Manifest Permission set to the application
- If Application installed under the system apps (and has right SE Policy)

Then you will be able to use `ContentProvider` to fetch all kind of information you need. To see the full support for TVContent Provider you can refer to [this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TvProvider/+/e6f7403/src/com/android/providers/tv/TvProvider.java) (ensure it's aligned with your Android OS version) and other AOSP information. For ex.

```
/**
 * Returns the current list of channels your app provides.
 *
 * @param resolver Application's ContentResolver.
 * @return List of channels.
 */
public static List<Channel> getChannels(ContentResolver resolver) {
    List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();
    // TvProvider returns programs in chronological order by default.
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = resolver.query(Channels.CONTENT_URI, Channel.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return channels;
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            channels.add(Channel.fromCursor(cursor));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get channels", e);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return channels;
}
```

Another ex.

```
TvInputManager tv = (TvInputManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE);

    List<TvInputInfo> list = tv.getTvInputList();
    String[] projection =  {
            TvContract.Channels._ID,
            TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NUMBER
    };

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Iterator<TvInputInfo> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        TvInputInfo aux = it.next();
        Uri uri = TvContract.buildChannelsUriForInput(aux.getId());

        Log.d("TAG", uri.toString());
        Log.d("TAG", aux.toString());

        Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null ,null);
        Log.d("TAG", cur.toString());

        if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "not empty cursors");
        }

    }
```

UPDATE:

The basic permission you should have(Also refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel)):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.READ_EPG_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.WRITE_EPG_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EPG_DATA"/>
```

Comment: For the second example, in my case it get stuck in 'applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE)  as TvInputManager' without any message. Am I missing permissions or anything here?

Comment: @RalfWickum 2. I'm not sure, that you are required to get this `TVInputManager`. You can use first example to receive TV Info.  2. If you cannot request it from the `Context`, it means that current device doesn't have this service (not supported).

Comment: 1. How is the resolver? I tried that already, but I get only channels of a certain dedicated provider, not all providers..  2. Since I cant even create the TvInputManager I cant access 'TvInfo'

Comment: @RalfWickum I'm not sure I got your point. - If you cannot request `TvInputManager`(and further `TvInputInfo`), it means you don't have permission or it's not supported by the system. - From your question above, you can find all the information in `ContentProvider`, first snippet. Try to request play with query to get all the channels information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156928/why-contentresolver-returns-channels-but-empty-previewprograms ContentProvider delivers the channels but these are empty...

Comment: _If All the Manifest Permission set to the application_ can you name them? I only have `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`

Comment: @RalfWickum `android:sharedUserId` it's not a permission. Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element. And one more note, your question was completely changed from the initial one.

Comment: As you can see in the original post after the "EDIT" tag, I pointed out that your first two lines of your second example wont work. The tvlist is empty. For the content resolver I have another Thread. Here, I am only insterested in the TV Input Manager solution.

Comment: @RalfWickum If you can ready carefully you can find answer to your question. Both request above work fine. If you are not able to receive list of TvInfo, your  device HAL to TvInput is not set correctly or you don't have right permission.