# Why do I not get all Channel items visible in Android TV provider database?

Tags: android-tv, android-contentresolver

First of all, this is the `/data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db`
[image]

Then in my code I applied [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66001312/5102206) to retrieve the channels:

```
TvInputManager tv = (TvInputManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE);
List<TvInputInfo> list = tv.getTvInputList();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Iterator<TvInputInfo> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    TvInputInfo aux = it.next();
    Uri uri = TvContract.buildChannelsUriForInput(aux.getId());

    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null ,null);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    do {
        val channel = Channel.fromCursor(channelCursor)
        Log.d("Log", "New channel ${channel.id} : ${channel.displayName} : ${channel.packageName}"}
    } while (channelCursor.moveToNext() && channelCursor.isLast.not())
}
```

Unfortunately, I get as input_id for `TvInputInfo aux` only

> com.google.android.videos/.tv.usecase.tvinput.playback.TvInputService

thus my cursor returns only 1 Channel with `_id = 4`.

Despite, I did neither got the input_id's `_id=22` for amazon nor `_id=25` for netflix, as listed in the screenshot above, I would like to get all above shown 18 Channels.

How can I query **all** Channels, also those with an empty `input_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get restricted by `TvContract.buildChannelsUriForInput(aux.getId());` what depends on input_id. When you take `TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI` for Uri, you will get:

```
Uri uri = TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI;

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null ,null);
cur.moveToFirst();

do {
    val channel = Channel.fromCursor(channelCursor)
    Log.d("Log", "New channel ${channel.id} : ${channel.displayName} : ${channel.packageName}"}
} while (channelCursor.moveToNext())
```